Movie from 80's- 90s where someone find a way (serum maybe ?) to live forever and sells it to rich people while charging them half their fortune
I remember that a guy invents or discover a way to live forever, maybe by a serum that gets injected into people. He meets rich, ultra rich people and sells them the solution at the price of "half their fortune because they will have another life to make up the rest of their money".
Couldn't see it, only saw the tv ads for it and that's it but have been wanting to see it since then.
Was in late 80's possibly 90s or maybe even early 2000, honestly don't remember when.

Just want to highligth: it's not a funny, laughable movie.

Plot sounds quite similar to Joe Haldeman's book The Long Habit of Living but a quick search doesn't show any movie adaptation.  (The book's rules are even worse, as I recall - all of your fortune, with a minimum value of $1M, gets you a 10-year extension to your life.  Naturally, the rich have worked out ways to game the system.)

https://www.ranker.com/list/best-immortality-movies-list/ranker-film https://whatnerd.com/best-movies-about-immortals-ranked/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Films_about_immortality looking over multiple lists and so many vampire movies to weed through... nothing seems to match your description though lol

https://www.imdb.com/list/ls066955083/ I'm bored and looking over lists to find a movie that sounds similar and I'm not seeing anything. I really enjoyed In Time but it's not the same story.

Death becomes her. (July 31st, 1992)
Wikipedia link
Starring:
Meryl Streep,
Goldie Hawn,
Bruce Willis,
Isabella Rossellini.

Copyright Universal pictures 1992, fair usage. Source: ranker.com

In 1978, a narcissistic fading actress Madeline Ashton performs in a
Broadway musical. She invites long-time frenemy, the meek aspiring
writer Helen Sharp, backstage along with Helen's fiancé, famed plastic
surgeon Ernest Menville. Smitten with Madeline, Ernest breaks off his
engagement with Helen to marry Madeline. Seven years later, a lonely,
obese, depressed, and destitute Helen is committed to a psychiatric
hospital where she obsesses over taking revenge against Madeline.
Another seven years later, Madeline and Ernest live an opulent but
miserable life in Beverly Hills: Madeline is depressed about her age
and withering beauty and Ernest, now an alcoholic, has been reduced to
working as a reconstructive mortician. After receiving an invitation
to a party celebrating Helen's new book, Madeline rushes for beauty
treatments. Desperate to look younger, Madeline is given the business
card of Lisle Von Rhuman, a mysterious, wealthy socialite who
specializes in rejuvenation.
Madeline and Ernest attend Helen's party and discover that Helen is
now slim, glamorous and youthful despite being fifty years old.
Jealous of Helen's appearance, Madeline observes as Helen tells Ernest
that she blames Madeline for his career decline. Madeline later visits
her young lover but discovers he is with a woman of his own age.
Despondent, Madeline drives to Lisle's mansion. The youthful Lisle
claims to be seventy-one years old and offers Madeline a potion that
promises eternal life and youth. Madeline drinks the potion, which
reverses her age, restoring her beauty, but Lisle warns her that she
must disappear from the public eye after ten years, to avoid suspicion
of her immortality, and treat her body well.

It goes downhill for the characters after that - in a satirical look at the vanity of Hollywood and the TV industry, and society's obsession/infatuation with youth.
The actual cost is never stated, but it involves a lot of zero on Madeleine's check, and Lisle states the cost depends on the subject.

Ah, the sordid topic of coin. I'm
afraid it's not so simple. The cost,
you see, is different for everyone.


No worries. :-D I'd happened on the film in my own search, but discounted it because I was assuming an explicit cost.

Thanks but no, this is not the movie i was looking for. It was a bit darker - not humoristic at all

Oh, OK. I'm curious to know what it might be now.  @Julian

@Julian Are you sure? It's a pretty dark comedy, especially if you dive into the implications :D

The broad concept has been used a few times in written SF.  I think Heinlein used it, for example, probably before his major novels considering longevity and immortality.  I wonder how many films have been inspired by it
